CSS grid: prevent a specific cell with lengthy text from setting the width of its column
In a grid layout with two columns I have several rows with similar content, while the last row has in its first cell a lengthier text.
I use display: inline-grid and grid-template-columns: auto auto
for the container to minimize its width without linebreaks/soft wraps for the short texts in the regular columns (min-content won't do). But I do want soft wraps for the text in the last row so it won't be the one which sets the width of the row and container.


.grid-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  border: 1px solid darkcyan;
}

.cell1 {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

.cell2 {
  text-align: left;
}

.cell1-special {
  grid-column: 1 /span 1;
  align-self: left;
  background-color: rgba(128, 0, 0, 0.35);
}
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="cell1">total number N=</div>
  <div class="cell2">100 ... 200</div>
  <div class="cell1">repeat number M=</div>
  <div class="cell2">1 or 2</div>
  <div class="cell1">rate r=</div>
  <div class="cell2">0.1-0.2</div>
  <div class="cell1-special">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  <div class="cell2"></div>
</div>



or as jsFiddle.
Is it possible, using just css, to prevent the cell in the last row to set the width of its column? I expect the simple answer is no, but I'm thinking that maybe there's a creative solution based on restructuring the grid, adding a subgrid, an empty column, some smart use of css functions, etc.
Since the cell texts are server-generated, I can't have a static measure of the texts, but I can rearrange the data any way I need to. So I don't think a solution based on a fixed size would be acceptable, like grid-template-columns: fit-content(130px) auto;, but at least the snippet below illustrates exactly what I am looking for:


.grid-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: fit-content(120px) auto;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  border: 1px solid darkcyan;
}

.cell1 {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

.cell2 {
  text-align: left;
}

.cell1-special {
  grid-column: 1 /span 1;
  align-self: left;
  background-color: rgba(128, 0, 0, 0.35);
}
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="cell1">total number N=</div>
  <div class="cell2">100 ... 200</div>
  <div class="cell1">repeat number M=</div>
  <div class="cell2">1 or 2</div>
  <div class="cell1">rate r=</div>
  <div class="cell2">0.1-0.2</div>
  <div class="cell1-special">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  <div class="cell2"></div>
</div>




Using the techniques described here you probably can.

Thanks @Paulie_D, on a fast browse I didn't see how to apply those to my case, but I'll take a more attentive look.

Not sure it will work but I'm looking at it.

Seems pretty easy, include the whole code please including the html, it will be alot quicker to fix.

@JulesUK, the snippets also include the HTML. There's nothing else to it; if you find it easier to work with it, I added a jsFiddle version of the snippet.

I suggest using contain:inline-size which means that its contents will be treated as if they were zero width for the purpose of its contribution to the auto grid column sizing.


.grid-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  border: 1px solid darkcyan;
}

.cell1 {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

.cell2 {
  text-align: left;
}

.cell1-special {
  grid-column: 1 /span 1;
  align-self: left;
  background-color: rgba(128, 0, 0, 0.35);
  contain: inline-size;
}
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="cell1">total number N=</div>
  <div class="cell2">100 ... 200</div>
  <div class="cell1">repeat number M=</div>
  <div class="cell2">1 or 2</div>
  <div class="cell1">rate r=</div>
  <div class="cell2">0.1-0.2</div>
  <div class="cell1-special">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  <div class="cell2"></div>
</div>




Incredible how beautifully simple it can be done, and it works perfectly, thank you very much. I'll welcome other approaches, but I doubt anything can beat this in efficiency!
